# sed: string between single qoutes

Tags: sed

I want to put an capital E infront of every string.
It is important that I use sed.

Such that

```
(260,'\"$40 a Day\"',2002,'Color','USA','','2000100002',131,6.1,'2002-04-24')
```

becomes

```
(260,E'\"$40 a Day\"',2002,E'Color',E'USA',E'',E'2000100002',131,6.1,E'2002-04-24')
```

I have tried

```
sed "s/'.*'/E&/g"
```

but it only puts an E infront of the first string!

Regards Kim

Comment: I see that your strings can contain escaped double-quotes.  Are they guaranteed _not_ to contain escaped single-quotes?

Answer (score 1):

The greedy matching of `*` is matching from the first single quote all the way to the very last one. Try this instead:

```
sed "s/'[^']*'/E&/g"
```

As John1024 warns above, this will not work if escaped single-quotes are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`,

```
sed "s/,'/,E'/g"
```